# Mocking imported modules for a service

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nestjs

Suppose i want to write a unit test for a service which depends on services of another module.

Now here is my question. Is there any way to write my test so that i mock the module that `MyService` depends on such that i can use it in my unit test like this:

```
const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [
        MockedModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        MyService,
    ],
});
```

Or i have to write a mock for each dependency service and use them like this:

```
const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [
        MyService,
        {
            provider: DependencyService,
            useClass: DependencyServiceMock,
        }
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it would be possible to use a `MockModule` that provides and exports the same dependencies that the service would normally depend on. I haven't heard of someone trying that yet, but I don't see why it wouldn't work. So if you have

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private readonly depService: DependencyService) {}
...
}
```

Then in your mock module you would need

```js
@Module({
  providers: [{
    provide: DependencyService,
    useClas: DependencyServiceMock,
  }],
  exports: [DependencyService],
})
export class MockedModule {}
```

And in your test you would need to do

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  const app = await Test.createTestModule({
    imports: [MockedModule],
    providers: [MySerivce],
  }).compile();
});
...
```